# How to make global rule for datagridview to not allow negative, null or blank inputs

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridview

I'm looking for a way to make a global rule across my entire datagridview, that if a user inputs a negative number or leaves one of the datagridviewcells blank, a message-box will tell the user that an invalid entry has occured. After the message-box I want to be able to supply a default value for the datagridviewcell, "na". My datagridview is connected to an excel spreadsheet using the oledataadapter. So far I have this code I found on MSDN, but when I use this, my program isn't compiling correctly. Is there somewhere else I can use this code besides the cellvalidating event? If not, I would greatly appreciate any other suggestions or ideas on the matter. Thanks so much!

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e _
As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
Handles dataGridView1.CellValidating

Me.dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "" 
Dim newInteger As Integer 


If dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return 
If Not Integer.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), newInteger) _
    OrElse newInteger < 0 Then

    e.Cancel = True 
    Me.dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "the value must be a non-negative integer" 

End If
```

End Sub

Comment: have you try my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in EditingControlShowing event ...

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    Try
        'remove if there is already a handler
        RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyPress, AddressOf TextNumberKeypress
        'add handler
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyPress, AddressOf TextNumberKeypress

    Catch ex As Exception
        '... 
    End Try
End Sub


Sub TextNumberKeypress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim k As Byte = Asc(e.KeyChar)
    Dim s As String = "0123456789"

    If Not s.Contains(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True        
        If Not (k = 8 Or k = 13 Or k = 1 Or k = 3 Or k = 22) Then e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```